# Can not read properties of undefined (reading 'split')

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, split

I wrote some code to create arrays of objects in js files based on data in txt files as follows:

```
var num1 = ['100', '200', '500', '1000']
var num2 = ['10', '20', '30', '40', '50']

for (var i of num1) {
    for (var j of num2) {
        var source = './dat/txt/data_' + i + '_' + j + '.txt'
        var dest = './dat/js/data_' + i + '_' + j + '.js'
        var write = '[\n'
        fs.readFile(source, 'utf-8', function (err, data) {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err)
            }
            var datArray = data.split('\r\n')
            for(let k=0;k<parseInt(i);k++){
                var numbers = datArray[k].split(' ')
                write = write.concat('{\npos:\nx:',numbers[0],',\ny:',numbers[1],'\n},\nbeta:',numbers[2],'\n},')
            }
        })
        fs.writeFile(dest, write, (err) => {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err)
            } else console.log('Written successfully')
        })
    }
}
```

The txt files have the format as follow:

```
1 2 3
1 2 3
1 2 3
....
```

And I want to create Arrays of objects as follow:

```
[
  {
    pos: {
      x: 1,
      y: 2,
    },
    beta: 3
  },
  ...
]
```

When I run the code, it has this Error:

```
var numbers = datArray[k].split(' ')
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'split')
```

I tried log the array datArray and it's a normal Array of Strings, and the length of datArray equals value of i. The output files also only write a single character '[' and a line break.
What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Array's index start at 0, so, your index must be lower than the array's length

Comment: Well, `console.log(k, datArray, datArray[k])` to see what you’re trying to do…

Comment: By the way, even with this fixed, it won't work because you are running `writeFile` before `readFile` is even finished. Either use the sync variants such as `readFileSync` or learn about asynchronicity.

Comment: Also, because you are using `var` instead of `let` in your `for`s and the `readFile` call is asynchronous, all the `for`s will complete before the first file is even read, and `i` will have value `1000` by then (for all of them). If you'd use `let` (or better even, `const`, since you don't modify `i` anyways), it would be separate `i`s that keep their value. This is probably your issue. (To see what I mean, try `for (var i of [1,2,3,4]) setTimeout(() => console.log(i), 100)` - prints `4 4 4 4` - vs. the same with `let`/`const` - prints `1 2 3 4`.)

Comment: I suggest you learn how to use a debugger with node.js, that would show you much better what actually runs in what order and when, and what values the variables have at each point...

Answer (score 0):

i think to solve this problem
change this line:

```
var numbers = datArray[k].split(' ')
```

with this :

```
var numbers = datArray[k]?.split(' ')
```